# Get index/position of element and it's Name in Javascript [ DOM ]

Tags: javascript

I try to find the index position and name of div element in container but whenever i try it is not give me the correct outPut.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div>This is div</div>
    <p>This is Paragraph</p>
    <script>
    let x = document.getElementById("container")
    let y = x.childNodes;
    for(let i =0; i < y.length ; i++)
    {
        if(y[i].nodeType == 2)
        {
            alert(y[i].nodeName);
            }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think you're after nodeType of `1` (or `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`) and to use `innerText` instead of `nodeName`

Comment: when i use y[i].nodeType == 1 it looks like div and p are indexed at position 1

Comment: you don't have any type 2 element in your list.. you have type 3 and 1 type element.

Comment: i want the div to be at the index position 1 and p to be at the index position 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space bars, new lines and tabs between 2 tags are considered as one text node. So there is a node before inner DIV. Similarly, there is a text node between inner DIV and P element.

Checking the 'tagName' property of each child node inside for loop will also work. Text nodes do not have 'tagName' property.

```
<div id="container">
<div>This is div</div>
<p>This is Paragraph</p></div>
<script>
let x = document.getElementById("container")
let y = x.childNodes;
for(let i =0; i < y.length ; i++) {
    if(y[i].tagName && (y[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "DIV" || y[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "P")) {
        alert(i + ": " + y[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: but when use nodeType it show that DIV and P both are indexed at position 1 !!! how can we set the DIV to be at index position 1 and P to be at index position 2??

Comment: But DIV is at index 1 and P is at index 3. You can check it by adding value of 'i' in alert(). I edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The nodeType property returns the node type, as a number, of the specified node.

If the node is an element node, the nodeType property will return 1.

**If the node is an attribute node, the nodeType property will return 2.**

If the node is a text node, the nodeType property will return 3.

If the node is a comment node, the nodeType property will return 8.

```js
     let x = document.getElementById("container")
        let y = x.childNodes;
        for(let i =0; i < y.length ; i++)
        {
            if(y[i].nodeType == 1)
            {
                alert(y[i].nodeName);
                }
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div>This is div</div>
        <p>This is Paragraph</p>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: why div and p are indexed at position 1?? what can i do to get div at index position 1 and p at index position 2

Comment: it is not position it is type  position is index of Y

Answer (score 1):

Based On the solution from MBadrian
as far as you managed to get the nodeName then you can set your condition based on the Name of the Node, now if you want to get specific nodes you can get their text content and set your condition based on that...
the below code is the same as MBadrian answer only I replaced the return of nodeName and returned the textContent

```
  let x = document.getElementById("container")
    let y = x.childNodes;
    for(let i =0; i < y.length ; i++)
    {
      console.log(y[i].nodeType)
        if(y[i].nodeType == 1)
        {
            alert(y[i].textContent);
            }
    }
```

Comment: seems DIV and P both are indexed at position 1 i want DIV to be at position 1 and P to be at a Position 2  .